# How to use tf.data's initializable iterator and reinitializable interator and feed data to estimator api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

All the official google tutorials use the one shot iterator for all the estimator api implementation, i couldnt find any documentation on how to use tf.data's initializable iterator and reinitializable interator instead of one shot iterator.

Can someone kindly show me how to switch between train_data and test_data using tf.data's initializable iterator and reinitializable interator. We need to run a session to use feed dict and switch the dataset in the initializable iterator, its a low level api and its confusing how to use it part of estimator api architecture

PS : I did find that google mentions 
"Note: Currently, one-shot iterators are the only type that is easily usable with an Estimator."

But is there any work around within the community? or should we just stick with one shot iterator for some good reason

Comment: Just curious: were you using `from_string_handle` before you started using `Estimator`?

Comment: Nope, i just started with estimators, @EricAuld can i know why you asked?

Answer (score 5):

To use either initializable or reinitializable iterators, you must create a class that inherits from tf.train.SessionRunHook. This class then have access to the session used by the tf.estimator functions.

Here is quick example that you can adapt to your needs :

```
class IteratorInitializerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IteratorInitializerHook, self).__init__()
        self.iterator_initializer_func = None # Will be set in the input_fn

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        self.iterator_initializer_func(session) 


def get_inputs(X, y):
    iterator_initializer_hook = IteratorInitializerHook()

    def input_fn():
        X_pl = tf.placeholder(X.dtype, X.shape)
        y_pl = tf.placeholder(y.dtype, y.shape)

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_pl, y_pl))
        dataset = ...
        ...

        iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
        next_example, next_label = iterator.get_next()


        iterator_initializer_hook.iterator_initializer_func = lambda sess: sess.run(iterator.initializer,
                                                                                    feed_dict={X_pl: X, y_pl: y})

        return next_example, next_label

    return input_fn, iterator_initializer_hook

...

train_input_fn, train_iterator_initializer_hook = get_inputs(X_train, y_train)
test_input_fn, test_iterator_initializer_hook = get_inputs(X_test, y_test)

...

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,
                hooks=[train_iterator_initializer_hook])
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn,
                   hooks=[test_iterator_initializer_hook])
```

This is a modified version from a code I found in a [blogpost](https://k-d-w.org/blog/2017/12/denoising-autoencoder-as-tensorflow-estimator/)  by [Sebastian Pölsterl](https://k-d-w.org/). Have a look under the "Feeding data to an Estimator via the Dataset API" section.

Comment: I need to experiment with your approach will keep you posted, thanks

Comment: This approach is also explained at https://k-d-w.org/blog/103/denoising-autoencoder-as-tensorflow-estimator

Comment: Thanks ! I completely forgot where I got this from originally. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate
It allows you to use validation during training without needing to care about iterator at all.

Comment: `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` is just a wrapper and doesn't answer this issue at all. If you need to use feed_dict for whatever reasons (in my example to assign a value to an input placeholder), you need an initializable iterator and a `tf.train.SessionRunHook`.

Comment: In case you only need to switch between train and test, why not use train_and_evaluate?

Comment: Sure you can use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` or alternate between `estimator.train` and `estimator.evaluate` if your input function can be initialized with a `one_shot_iterator` but this is not the case of all input functions (for example, if your dataset is > 2 GB) and the question clearly states that they need to pass a feed dict. I would also recommend to stay away from `one_shot_iterator` as it makes your input graph really big.