# Feed tf.estimator.Estimator.predict batch by batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have a trained estimator model and I need to get the prediction vectors of a very large dataset that does not fit in the memory, process these prediction vectors and save them. So far my code looks something like this:

```
def hist(predictions):
    ...
    return histograms

def input_fn(feat, batch_size=100):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feat))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x:...)
    return dataset

super_batch = 100
splits = data.shape[0]//super_batch

for s in range(splits):
    pred = list(classifier.predict(lambda: input_fn(data[s*super_batch:(s+1)*super_batch])))
    pred_cls = [p["classes"] for p in pred]
    hist_vec = hist(pred_cls)
    save hist_vec
```

I know this is not the correct way to do it, cause it leaves the GPU idle for a long time and because of loading the model every time I call the classifier.predict it takes a very very long time to run. Is there any way to use something like a feed function with estimators and speed this process up?

Comment: "I need to get the prediction vectors of a very large dataset that does not fit in the memory". I'm not sure what you mean. Is `data` too big to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`? Because it fits into your RAM or you wouldn't be able to slice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm assuming that the issue is with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`**

---

If you use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` with numpy arrays in Tensorflow 1.0 with eager mode disabled, it embeds the values in the graph as one or more `tf.constant` operations. The bigger your dataset is, the bigger the graph becomes. This is very inefficient and you can face `ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB` errors.

With `tf.estimator`, you have 2 solutions:

- Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. Just convert `feat` into a Python Generator and you are good to go. The performances are a bit worse than `from_tensor_slices` as the `tf.data` graph's speed is limited by the Python runtime.
- Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` with Tensorflow placeholders. This is more complicated but the most efficient one. Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633489/10025506) for more informations. The gist of it is that you need to create a specific hook to initialize the placeholders after the session is created inside the estimator.

Comment: thanks! the second method is exactly what I wanted :)